# How to scrape website data called by javascript

Tags: javascript

First post here - apologies in advance if i've made any mistakes. I would like to scrape the median house price for all the suburbs on this map. The median house price appears when you roll your mouse over the suburb in the map. ideally the output would be in excel with first column suburb name, second column median price with about 100 or so suburbs (i.e. columns). I do not know any programming and have tried to use parsehub (https://www.parsehub.com/) to do this but have not had any luck.

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know! pls find link to map below:

http://www.realestate.com.au/invest/2-bed-unit-in-st+marys,+nsw+2760?zoom=10

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is rather vague. Where are you stuck exactly? The only suggestion that could be given right now is "try harder, good luck".

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question does not lend itself to Stackoverflow's type of questions as seen in [help]. You would get a better chance at elance.com or such sites. Actually you are not as seen in their [legal blurb](http://www.realcommercial.com.au/static/rca/legal.html): **Restrictions on use of Websites**
In accessing or using our websites you agree that you will not:

use any automated device, software, process or means to access, retrieve, scrape, or index our websites or any content on our website;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PhantomJS

"PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG."

This will allow you to use JavaScript to scrape data from a page. Another suggestion is using Import.IO. The service is free and doesn't require any programming to scrap the data. The service will give you an API to call which returns JSON data. The data is stored on their servers and is relatively fast.

Answer (score 0):

One of the founders of ParseHub here. At the moment, ParseHub can only extract data from SVG-based maps, not canvas-based maps. I realize this is a technical detail that probably doesn't matter to you. We're looking into a workaround for your problem, expect an email from me soon.

On a side note, while we may be able to solve this from a technical standpoint, we strongly encourage you to abide by the terms of service of any site that you extract data from.

-Serge